# Minecraft /give tnt fuse command problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you use

> /give

Command in minecraft to give yourself tnt that has a short fuse because I can't seem to do it properly.

I have tried doing

> /give @p minecraft:tnt 1 {Fuse:80}

But it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Fuse` tag is an NBT tag for blocks not for items. therefor you could do something like this:

```
/summon PrimedTnt ~ ~1 ~ {Fuse:80}
```

This will spawn a TNT on the ground with a custom fuse.

Comment: Although this works what I'm asking for is giving myself it I know its possible because I have seen it done.

Comment: I'm sorry but the `Fuse` tag just doesn't work with the `/give` command.

Comment: The `Fuse` tag is an NBT tag for entities, not for blocks.